# jQuery - Search for similar elements in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to search in an array for similar elements. For example if in my array I have the name elements like `Sarah, sara, sarah` and in the input field I type and search for `sara` the result should give me all the similar result.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thL2w316/) however, it just looks for the correct element and it is not case insensitive.

How can approach this in order to have a case insensitive search and like the sql search `LIKE %...%`;

So far I have

```
$("#SearchBtn").click(function() {

  var searchInput = $("#SearchInput").val();

  if (searchInput == "") {

    alert("Search field is empty");

  } else {

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

      if ((array[i][0] == searchInput) || (array[i][1] == searchInput) || (array[i][2] == searchInput) || (array[i][3] == searchInput) || (array[i][4] == searchInput)) {

        alert(array[i]);

      }

    }

  }

});
```

Comment: Please mention exact i/p and o/p

Comment: why don't you define your `array` as a list of lowercase values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the case insensitive part, you can use toLowerCase both on input string and search string.

After that you can use indexOf to find if the input string is "similar" to your search pattern.

However, similarity between strings might be a bit more complicated. For example, you could consider that "sora" is similar to "sara" while "sarasara" not...

In that case, you would need [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) or similar distance functions and a similarity threshold.

In addition, toLowerCase might not work with respect to globalization, and you would have to consider [toLocalLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase).

Have a look at the simple version in this fiddle:

```js
var array = [
  ["Andrew", "London", "Male", "waiter", "single"],
  ["John", "rome", "Male", "designer", "Married"],
  ["Sarah", "new York", "Female", "broker", "single"],
  ["Annah", "UK", "Female", "waiter", "maRRied"],
  ["sara", "Tokio", "Female", "Waiter", "single"],
  ["John", "Naples", "male", "Chef", "married"]
];

//Search Box

$("#SearchBtn").click(function() {

  var searchInput = $("#SearchInput").val().toLowerCase();

  if (searchInput == "") {

    alert("Search field is empty");

  } else {

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if ((array[i][0].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput) >= 0) 
      ||(array[i][1].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput) >= 0)
      ||(array[i][2].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput) >= 0)
      ||(array[i][3].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput) >= 0)
      ||(array[i][4].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput) >= 0)) {

    alert (array[i]);

      } 

    }

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="custom-search-form" class="form form-inline navbar-form ">
  <div class="input-group">

    <input id="SearchInput" type="text" name="mapSearch" value="" placeholder="Key Search" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button id="SearchBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="height:25px;">Search</button>
                </span>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use *toLowerCase()* here

`if ((array[i][0] == searchInput)`

Comment: thank you. I have tried to give to the `searchInput` `toLowerCase()` however, it will search for lower case elements

Answer (score 0):

You can check here: https://jsfiddle.net/u7gkt2Lc/

```
var array = [
  ["Andrew", "London", "Male", "waiter", "single"],
  ["John", "rome", "Male", "designer", "Married"],
  ["Sarah", "new York", "Female", "broker", "single"],
  ["Annah", "UK", "Female", "waiter", "maRRied"],
  ["sara", "Tokio", "Female", "Waiter", "single"],
  ["John", "Naples", "male", "Chef", "married"]
];

//Search Box

$("#SearchBtn").click(function() {

  var searchInput = $("#SearchInput").val();

  if (searchInput == "") {

    alert("Search field is empty");

  } else {



    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

      for(var j = 0; j <= 4 ; j++ ) {
      if (array[i][j].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        alert (array[i][j]);
      }
      }

    }

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you can use the toLowerCase() function to make everything lowercase. Make sure that you make both the elements in the array as well as the input.val() lowercase.

When you've done that, you can simply use the indexOf function, which searches through an array and returns the index.

Then we know, that if the index is greater than -1 (since 0 is the first index), then there must be a match.

You can use something similar to this:

```
   if(array[i][0].indexOf(searchInput) > -1) {
        alert('There's a match!')
   }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to compare case sensitivity.

```js
var array = [
   ["Andrew", "London", "Male", "waiter", "single"],
   ["John", "rome", "Male", "designer", "Married"],
   ["Sarah", "new York", "Female", "broker", "single"],
   ["Annah", "UK", "Female", "waiter", "maRRied"],
   ["sara", "Tokio", "Female", "Waiter", "single"],
   ["John", "Naples", "male", "Chef", "married"]
];
//Search Box
$("#SearchBtn").click(function() {
   var searchInput = $("#SearchInput").val();
   if (searchInput == "") {
      alert("Search field is empty");
   } 
 else {
      array.map(function(d) {
         d.map(function(e) {
            if (searchInput.toLowerCase() == e.toLowerCase()) {
               alert(e);
            }
         })
      })
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="custom-search-form" class="form form-inline navbar-form ">
   <div class="input-group">

      <input id="SearchInput" type="text" name="mapSearch" value="" placeholder="Key Search" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button id="SearchBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="height:25px;">Search</button>
                </span>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and this String object.
Use following case insensitive RegExp for comparison:

```
var oRegExp = new RegExp(/John/i);
var sArrayElement = "john"
sArrayElement.search(oRegExp);
```